# facebook php sdk - access token is empty

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I would like to ask a facebook timeline and photo gallery, but the access token is null.

```
$this->FaceBookApp = new Facebook\Facebook(array(
        "app_id" => $this->appID,
        "app_secret" => $this->appSecret,
        "default_graph_version" => "v2.5"
));
$helper = $this->FaceBookApp->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = array('user_posts');
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl( _WEBPAGE .'/facebook-sdk/printAccessToken.php', $permissions);
echo "<script>window.top.location.href='".$loginUrl."'</script>";
```

callback php:

```
$helper = $this->FaceBookApp->getCanvasHelper();
try {
            $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            // When Graph returns an error
            echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            // When validation fails or other local issues
            echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
}
var_dump($accessToken);
```

when i try without access token, the

```
$response = $this->FaceBookApp->get('/'.$userId.'/feed', $this->appID .'|'. $this->appSecret);
var_dump( $response->getDecodedBody() );
```

is empty array.

Please, help me.

Comment: There are a couple of checks that might help you: 1) are you testing this as an admin of the app? you need to approve the permission before you request it from normal users 2) try your calls on the Graph API Explorer and see what you are getting there 3) try following one of the samples in the docs and on github: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4#usage